# Kubernetes load balancer in GKE is not accesible with curl

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-service

I'm debugging an application running on a `Dev` environment running in `Google Kubernetes Engine` and want to send `curl` based `HTTP` requests to the `LoadBalancer` which selects some pods.

```
$ kubectl get svc -n mynamespace -o wide 
NAME       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)
mylb   LoadBalancer         1.1.1.1      2.2.2.2   1111:22222/TCP
```

So as far as I understand `CLUSTER-IP` is used for access from within the `Kubernetes` cluster itself while `EXTERNAL-IP` is used for access from the outside. So I tried the following

```
$curl -X GET https://2.2.2.2:1111/path
curl: (35) error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer
```

So this request does not seem to reach the POD behind the `LoadBalancer`.

Maybe I completely misused the concept of service and `LoadBalancer`? What is the proper way to send requests to `POD`s behind a `LoadBalancer`?

Is there a way to trace requests coming to the LoadBalancer and log which POD it was forwarded (or not forwarded)?

Comment: Are you mapping your service correctly to your deployment here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with looking at your [service logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/service/cluster-location/cluster-name/namespace/service-name/logs?project=project-id).  See if you can find anything there.

If you don't see any traffic there, you could try enabling [VPC flow Logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/subnetworks/details/region/subnet-name?project=project-id).  Allow a little time after enabling, try to curl again and see what shows up in the flow logs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to check those logs with `kubectl` or other console tool?